# Django update without required fields

Tags: django, api, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to execute an update through my `API`.  When I push an update, I do not have all the required fields, because I'm only trying to update the ones that have changed.  I get a `400 "This field is required."` error.

I know the field is required, but I'm trying to just update, not put in all my required fields again.  This is a `PUT` request.  This occurs before create or update are called on my `serializers`.  It fails on the `is_valid()` call (which I do not override).  Honestly, there isn't any relevant code to show.  To fix this do I have to override is_valid and provide a password there?

For example: Password is a required field in my model.  However I only push "first_name" because that's the only field that changed.  I will get: `password":["This field is required."]`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`UPDATE` is possible via 2 requests: `PUT and PATCH`

`PUT` updates all the fields of the object on which the operation is to be performed. It basically iterates over all the fields and updates them one by one. Thus, if a required field is not found in the supplied data, it will raise an error.

`PATCH` is what we call a Partial Update. You can update only the fields that are needed to be changed. Thus, in your case change your request method to `PATCH` and your work will be done.

Comment: The same with PATCH. It requires my "owner" field. Take in mind that "owner" field a PK.

Answer (score 4):

Add `partial = True` argument in serializer as such:

```py
serializer = BookSerializer(book, data=request.data, partial=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same error after many experiments found something, so added all fields in `serializer.py` in class meta, as shown below -

```py
class Emp_UniSerializer( serializers.ModelSerializer ):
    class Meta:
        model = table
        fields = '__all__'  # To fetch For All Fields
        extra_kwargs = {'std_code': {'required': False},'uni_code': {'required': False},'last_name': {'required': False},'first_name': {'required': False}}
```

Here, we can update any field, it won't show error `["This field is required."]`

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why it is sometimes that you look for hours for the answer, then ask, then immediately find the answer.  I simply changed my request to be a 'PATCH' instead of a 'PUT'.